# Wlan is not configured on kali

Tags: kali-linux

I have Kali Linux VM (VMware) running on a Win 10 host that only connects to the internet via Home WiFi.This is an Intel Wireless-3168 built-in on an ASRock450m AMD M.Board.You should normally have Wlan0 in ip a or ifconfig, which it used to. It only shows as eth0 but im connected without seeing any other wifi connections. In fact it never even ask me for the password!? I have scavenged across the internet looking for a solution and performed all troubleshooting available without resolution. Duplicated with centos. Any help here?

Comment: no, you should not have a wifi device in a VM, unless you took the wifi device away from your host operating system, and passed the raw hardware control to the VM. Which actually is technically non-trivial, as it requires extensive use of things like the IOMMU. Also, what's the point. If you're in a VM on a desktop operating system, it's the hypervisor's responsibility to handle the network connectivity. Otherwise, *only* the VM would have that network device, and your host could no longer use the network.

Comment: My "full" kali-Linux shows my Broadcom iface Wi-Fi connected. I got the driver for it.  With my Main Host WIN10 its kali is a VM. It used to show wlan, & I used airmon-ng with it. I cant explain it but I think WIN10 network config is corrupted, because its auto-bridging, when Kali is set to NAT.

Comment: The reason I know there is a difference because 1. working and using airmon-ng. 2.msf console allows you to set your  LHOST info (I am pretty sure it showed the connections via wlan0 and I remember it showed other information listed as tun0 (i think).

Answer (score 1):

Your host is using the WiFi device so it's not available for the guest. You could pass-through the WiFi device to the guest but then it won't be available for the host.

An alternative solution would be to buy a supported USB WiFi device and pass that through to the guest, leaving the built-in WiFi device for the host

Comment: Like I said, I have proof that I was indeed connecting with wlan0, not eth0. How else could airmong-ng work? Some of the answers I got were that it was bridging my internet connection from the host Wi-Fi, which sounds plausible since the bare-metal machine has the Broadcom driver and works as Wi-Fi should. There is a setting in actual vmx file that shows it to default to ethernet.0 on the virtual machine. This can be troubleshot by 2 methods. 1. Alter the vmx file to wlan0 leaving no ethernet. 2. is to duplicate that "full kali" on another laptop for testing.